# Communication or traffic in client server hazelcast deployments

Tags: hazelcast

In client server hazelcast deployments, Client opens tcp connection to server to perform its operations, So Is this a duplex connection ? If not will there be a connection opened from server to client as well.  If so why ? How does listener of a topic on client get message when a message is published by other client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazelcast client opens a TCP connection (TCP is bidirectional). So then, when the connection is established, it's used for the client-server/server-client communication. There is no need for the server to configure access to clients or set up any other connection.